# Multi-platform Base64 Encoding and decoding problems(Android to PC)

Tags: java, android, sockets, encryption, base64

Okay so here is the situation I am facing. I am building an android app with a login screen and encrypting the information to send to my server. After encrypting I am encoding the information using Base64 on android to send it to the server on my pc which is decoding in Base64 but it isn't doing it correctly. My server reports a encryption padding error.

This is the code for the encryption on Android:

```
import android.util.Base64;

    try {
        plainText = user.getBytes("UTF-8");
        user = EncryptInfo(plainText, publicKey);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }

private static String EncryptInfo(byte[] data,PublicKey key){
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

This is the code running on my pc on the server decoding the data:

```
import java.util.Base64;

//Decrypt the userpassword
byte[] plainText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData);
inputLine = decryptData(plainText);

private String decryptData(byte[] cipherText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{  
    // decrypt the ciphertext using the private key
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] newPlainText = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        //System.out.println( "Finish decryption: " );
        //System.out.println( new String(newPlainText, "UTF8") );
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return new String(newPlainText, "UTF8");
}
```

I've included the imports I'm using for the base64. Also this isn't the whole code but just the relevant bits. I don't fully understand base64 and all my searching hasn't lead me to an answer so any help would be very appreciated!

Edit: The reason I'm doing all this is to safely transport login credentials to a server. This works on my desktop app just fine. I copied the code from the desktop app but the encoding was the only thing that needed changing. I believe base 64 is part of the problem. Can't debug the app because I run amd so I have to run it right on my phone.

Comment: but what for are you using base64 at all? 7bit era is already over.

Comment: What makes you think base64 is the problem? If it is, it should be straight forward to pinpoint with some debug in both ends without complicating it with encryption.

Comment: I'm trying to easily move the data over sockets and for possible storage. Once again I don't know much about base64 but it worked in my desktop application. I'm basing my android app off the same code. If I could get rid of it and use something else that would be great. Turns out android includes an old version of the commons library so when I try to use an updated one it just says it can't find the method encodeAsString.

Comment: Base64 is unlikely to be the culprit .. but my point is that this can easily be ruled out by some simple debug. - debug what goes into base64 on client side and what comes out of base64 on server side. Is it the same?

Comment: @Edde I managed to debug it using notifications on my phone. The encryption seems to be more likely the culprit now. I use private/public key encryption where the app only has the public key and I hold the private(Randomly generated each session). So I guess now I have to look at what's happening there. I don't know why I thought it was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
 return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

After debugging I found that my encrypted data was being cut off at the halfway point. Using Base64.No_Wrap solved my problems. Just posting it so all will know. Android development is new to me so I guess I didn't even think of it.

Comment: It looks less like a base64 problem and is also unrelated to Android programming. The  problem seems to be that you expect to have your data on a single line (which your posted code does not show). Typically bass64 data have also a limited line length so your encoded data consist of multiple lines. See also [Wikipedia article for base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).